# ng-submit will not allow duplicate values

Tags: angularjs

Why does Angular not allow duplicate data to be submitted? I am using ng-list to write all points scored using a simple controller.

For example - If a player inputs '10' into my app and then another player also does the same the ng-submit will stop functioning completely. I haven't specified anything else to allow this to happen. How can I change this default behaviour so users are allowed to post duplicate values?

Controller:

```
  bowlingApp.controller('bowlPoints', function ($scope){
    $scope.bowlPoints = [];

    $scope.addBowlPoints = function() {
      $scope.bowlPoints.push($scope.enteredPoints);
    };
  });
```

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="addBowlPoints()" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Player Score</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="enteredPoints"> 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

  <tr>
    <ul>
      <td>Player </td>
      <td ng-repeat="points in bowlPoints ">{{points}}</td>
    </ul>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-submit` works fine, in your example it adds value to array `bowlPoints`, but you just can not to see it.
To see an array and that `ng-submit` works fine you can type `{{bowlPoints}}` in your HTML file.

But if you want to see all data in table and if you want your table will to update and `angular` dynamically add your columns - you need to add `track by` in your `ng-repeat`

```
<td ng-repeat="points in bowlPoints track by $index ">{{points}}</td>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/oFMm9Jqk034IRvS1qOCO?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I believe submit only does something if the form is dirty. Since the first submit will have cleared the dirty state, it won't do anything. You could try manually setting the dirty state of the form. Failing that, you could use `ng-click` instead and do the form submission yourself.